# Is there a default method for logging the coordinates of user clicks in R?

Tags: r, user-interface, animation

I'm augmenting an animation. As of now, a setup function uses a fixed layout for the starting position of one part of the animation. I'd like to augment it, such that the program logs the coordinates of user clicks and places the objects in these custom positions instead of the present fixed ones.

Is there a default way to log the position of user clicks in R and integrate them into an animation, as above?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are you looking for [`identify`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/identify.html)?

Comment: @Rui No, I don't think so. I want the user to be able to place the points anywhere on the display, not simply to get the nearest point on a graph. Unless I'm misunderstanding how identify can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the answer is `help("locator")`.
In the call below, accepts 5 mouse clicks and plots the respective points (`type = "p"`) in green.

```
plot(1:10)
X <- locator(n = 5, type = "p", col = "#4eee94", pch = 16)

# Sample output
X
#$x
#[1] 2.907651 2.482139 4.118723 6.409941 7.130038
#
#$y
#[1] 1.674012 4.198595 6.509833 8.429939 4.483055
```

[image]